# Bluetooth Mouse stopped working in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, mouse

My bluetooth mouse stopped working.  In the bluetooth setting I can see it listed and it says not setup.  When this has happened before I just clicked on it and after trying to connect it would allow me to delete it so I could re-connect it.  This time it will not bring up the delete option it just returns to the not connected status.  Is there some other way to delete the device so I can re-connect it.

Comment: Ubuntu 20?  There is no such release. Ubuntu uses *yy.mm* format (year.month of release) for all server & desktop releases, the *yy* being used only for IoT and specialist appliance/device releases (also suitable for cloud use) that can use *snap* packages only.  By Ubuntu 20 do you mean Ubuntu Core 20?  as it's a different product to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (desktop or server) that you tagged.

Comment: It is on my laptop so it is Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: Please edit your question to mention only Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, and not Ubuntu 20 (which is closest to Ubuntu Core 20 which is a different product thus very different system). I can then remove my comment :)

Comment: I was able to manually delete the mouse entry, but now it won't find it to set it up again.  I just started using the normal mouse receiver and it works fine.